Show that a sequence generated by mean value theorem is approaching to $a$
I was trying to give a new proof Taylor’s series by taking $f(x)-\sum^{n}_{i=0}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}$ and applying mean value theorem n times. To make this complete, this problem is needed to be solved.
Let $a<x$ be reals and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth and $f(x)≠0$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\xi_{n}$ be the sequence defined by $f^{(n)}(\xi_n)-f^{(n)}(a)=f^{(n+1)}(\xi_{n+1})(\xi_n-a)$ with $\xi_{0}=x$ and $a<\xi_{n+1}<\xi_{n}$ where  $\xi_{n+1}$ is generated from mean value theorem. Show that $\xi_{n}$ converges to $a$.
And what extra conditions must be satisfied so that this conjecture is true?
I searched in the internet and in mse and didn’t find an answer to this.
Note: You might be tempted to use Taylor’s theorem. Don’t use it since I use the proof of this statement to show Taylor’s theorem.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

If I understand correctly, as stated, the result is false. Indeed, the sequence $\{\xi_n\}$ is not uniquely determined by the MVT identity and can be chosen in such a way that it converges to a different value than $a$. To see this with an example, let $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Since $f$ and all of its derivatives are identically equal to $0$, the MVT identity is satisfied for all choices of $\xi_{n + 1} \in (a, \xi_n)$. For simplicity, assume that $a = 0$, $\xi_0 = 1$. Then $\xi_n$ can be a decreasing sequence that converges to $1/2$ (or to any other strictly positive number).

Would it change if f(x)≠0 for some x?

Because for when we consider f(x)=0, then it’s a trivial case of proving Taylor’s series

What does "new proof of Taylor's series" mean?  Please state the actual theorem you're trying to prove.  I don't think the conjecture you posed is what you really want to show, since it doesn't involve Taylor series at all. That conjecture sounds like a flawed strategy to prove some result about Taylor series that you have not told us.
If you're trying to prove a function that is infinitely differentiable on an interval $I$ is equal on $I$ to its Taylor series at each point in $I$, then your method is doomed because that result is simply not true in general. The function $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ when $x \not= 0$ and $f(0) = 0$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbf R$ and nonzero when $x \not= 0$, but $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \geq 0$, so the Taylor series of $f(x)$ at $0$ is identically $0$ and thus is not equal to $f(x)$ anywhere except at $x = 0$.
